# how to create a sub list for a specific string in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have Python nested list that I'm trying to organize and eventually count number of occurrences.  The nested list looks like:

```
[['22', '1'], ['21', '15'], ['11', '3'], ['31', '4'], ['41', '13'],...]
```

The first I want to do is create a sublist that only contains '1' corresponding to the second item in the nested list.  I was able to do this by the following command:

```
Subbasin_1 = []
Subbasin_1.append([x for x in Subbasins_Imp if x[1] == '1'])
print Subbasin_1
```

Giving these results, which are correct:

```
[['21', '1'], ['21', '1'], ['21', '1'], ['21', '1'], ['22', '1'],...]
```

Now I want to create another sublist that will give me all the '21' in the each nested list for Subbasin_1.  When I use the same line of script, but change the appropriate items, I get an empty list.  Not sure what is going on...?

```
OS_Count1 = []
OS_Count1.append([x for x in Subbasin_1 if x[0] == '21'])
print OS_Count1
```

Result is [[]]       ???  What's the difference between the two?
Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that your

```
[['21', '1'], ['21', '1'], ['21', '1'], ['21', '1'], ['22', '1'],...]
```

line could be produced by the code you gave.  Your `Subbasin_1.append` line appends a *list* to the empty list Subbasin_1, so you should get something like

```
[[['22', '1'], ['21', '1']]]
```

with one extra level of nesting.

If you avoid the unnecessary construction of an empty list + append, you should get what you want:

```
>>> Subbasins_Imp = [['22', '1'], ['21', '15'], ['11', '3'], ['31', '4'], ['41', '13'], ['21', '1']]
>>> 
>>> Subbasin_1 = [x for x in Subbasins_Imp if x[1] == '1']
>>> print Subbasin_1
[['22', '1'], ['21', '1']]
>>> OS_Count1 = [x for x in Subbasin_1 if x[0] == '21']
>>> print OS_Count1
[['21', '1']]
```

Alternatively, you could simply replace append by extend.  I don't recommend this, but it might help you to see what's happening:

```
>>> Subbasins_Imp = [['22', '1'], ['21', '15'], ['11', '3'], ['31', '4'], ['41', '13'], ['21', '1']]
>>> 
>>> Subbasin_1 = []
>>> Subbasin_1.extend([x for x in Subbasins_Imp if x[1] == '1'])
>>> print Subbasin_1
[['22', '1'], ['21', '1']]
>>> 
>>> OS_Count1 = []
>>> OS_Count1.extend([x for x in Subbasin_1 if x[0] == '21'])
>>> print OS_Count1
[['21', '1']]
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Works like a charm.  And you are right, the first append I did for Subbasin_1 was giving me a three level deep list.

Answer (score 2):

Your list comprehension `[x for x in Subbasins_Imp if x[1] == '1']` creates a list by itself, which means when you append that list to `Subbasin_1`, you end up with a doubly nested list.

Compare:

```
sub_imp = [['22', '1'], ['21', '15'], ['11', '3'], ['31', '4'], ['41', '13']]
sub_1 = [x for x in sub_imp if x[1] == '1']
sub_2 = []
sub_2.append([x for x in sub_imp if x[1] == '1'])

print(sub_1)
print(sub_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Running your code I obtained a triple nested list....

```
Sub = [[['21','1'],....]]
```

Instead of doing:

```
  Subbasin_1 = []
  Subbasin_1.append([x for x in Sub if x[1]=='1'])
```

Simple do the list comprehension :

```
Subbasin_1 = [x for x in Sub if x[1] == '1']
```

This will give you the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference which implies Subbasin_1 might be empty at the time of the call or doesn't contain the data you think it does. It might also be that Subbasin_1 is nested 3 layers deep, not 2.